# Selenium code to ignore all ssl certificate except invalid security certificate

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My requirement is to ignore all SSL certificate except invalid security certificate,

Also, Is their any way in selenium to get hold of the certificate?

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
```

above code ignores all certificates,
My requirement is to ignore all code except invalid security certificate.

```
Error code:SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: I dont have code. 
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
  profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
above code ignores all certificates, I need to ignore all certificate except invalid Security certifcates(Error code:SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full list of capabilities:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html

> **setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(boolean untrustedIssuer)**
>
> By default, when accepting untrusted SSL certificates, assume that these
>   certificates will come from an untrusted issuer or will be self
>   signed.
>
> **setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(boolean acceptUntrustedSsl)**
>
> Sets whether Firefox should accept SSL certificates which have expired,
>   signed by an unknown authority or are generally untrusted.

Comment: These two methods will be applicable for all kinds of certificate, My requirement is to ignore all certificate expect invalid Security certifcates(Error code:SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER).